# Microsoft Office Word Selected text is black

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2016

When I am selecting text in Office Word 365 it is black instead of grey. What is causing this?

I am using Microsoft Office 365

Example image:

[image: Click here]

What I've tried so far:

- Reinstalling Office
- Deleting all Add-Ins
- Deleting normal.dotm
- Deleting Options and Data in regedit

But nothing worked.

Comment: Can you please add an image to your question? It will help to clarify your issue.

Comment: Just added an example image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following these steps:

To solve the problem you need to:

1. Open **Window search bar** by pressing Window's flag logo button.
2. Search for **Windows Speech Recognition**, a little bar will open on top of your screen.
3. Right click the bar and select Off: **Do not listen to anything I say**
4. Right click the bar again and select **Exit**

It may take a few seconds to work!
If it doesn't work at first try repeating the passages above and wait few minutes.

*Uninstalling Word or Repairing or Reinstalling won't solve this issue.*

Either check [this url](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-mso_2019/selected-text-black-solved-microsoft-word-2019/7c68549a-a42e-48f9-bb2d-fbd79278a8d6?tm=1596139742675)

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem & getting extremely frustrated...
The INSTANT solution I found to this was to make sure '**Speech Recognition**' is turned **off**.
search for "**ease of access dictation**" under settings, select "**speech**" below the '**interaction**' heading in the left column.
under '**Dictate text and control your device using only your voice**' - make sure "Turn on Speech Recognition" is **TURNED OFF**
selected text highlighting will be back to default