# Removing border around characters that I'm typing

Tags: microsoft-word

There's this black border that keeps forming around everything I type, and I can't figure out what's causing it. It's not the "shading" option. It's something else, and I'm not sure what it is.

This is Word on macOS.

Here's an example to illustrate the issue:
[image]

Here's a screenshot after I selected the word "there"
[image]

Comment: Hi. Can you post a screenshot of how the ribbon looks when you select some of this text?

Comment: Looks like the black selection box is linked to speech recognition being enabled (but usually on windows) like: https://superuser.com/a/1574158/673426. I'm not sure why newly-typed text is getting selected, but there are some settings in options > general, like smart paragraph selection that could be doing it

Comment: @YisroelTech I will edit it into the OP

Comment: @YisroelTech It looks like there's no change in the ribbon? (actually I think the original image already selected the word "there")

Comment: @Cpt.Whale that sentence isn't "selected" if I'm understanding your comment correctly. I can place my cursor outside of that sentence and it's still highlighted