# Hyperlink in word isn't working?

Tags: microsoft-word

My word (on mac) seems to be having issues lately. When I copy and pasted a link into word, and if I press the "return" button when my cursor is at the end of the link, it usually turns the link into a hyperlink (you know the typical blue colored text with an underline that denotes it's a link), but now, it's showing me this

[image]

I think it's displaying some kind of source code here? How can I return it to normal?

If I copy and paste that text onto stackexcahnge, it just copies as:
[image]

Comment: Press Alt+F9 to turn off field codes

Comment: Which might be Fn/Opt/F9 depending on which way your F-Keys are defined. [& idk why the downvote, I wouldn't have known it was called a field code either]

Comment: @DavidPostill ah that was the problem. I had turned it on because someone on reddit thought my other word-related issue (https://superuser.com/questions/1766422/removing-border-around-characters-that-im-typing?noredirect=1#comment2748983_1766422) may be related to it